# How can I repair a leak in my bathroom faucet?

Tags: bathroom, faucet

I have a delta bathroom faucet. The hot side is dripping from under the faucet down the water line and dripping.  Turned off water shut off and took off handle.  There is still water under the handle and still dripping slowly. Could the shut off be bad and still letting water through?  Do I need a new water shut off valve?

Comment: You can find out by unscrewing the hot water line from the faucet itself under the sink. If that pipe/hose is still dripping, then your shutoff is bad. However, a bad shutoff valve won't make your faucet leak, so there's probably an issue with the faucet itself.

Answer (score -1):

If you can, take it back to where it was purchased and buy another brand.
I have been installing fixtures for over 30 yrs and that brand is the worst for reliability and problems. ( I now refuse to install them) What you are describing is way too common for that brand.